# Two Kindles synced to same account - reading location being shared, but not Kindle content?

Tags: kindle, amazon, kindle-paperwhite

I have two Kindles (both 10th Generation Paperwhite) and one Amazon account.

Both Kindles are registered to the one Amazon account and I have enabled Whispersync in my Amazon settings.

However, if I download a sample from amazon.co.uk to one Kindle, the content doesn't appear on the other Kindle.

Also, if I buy a book from the Kindle store on one Kindle, it doesn't appear on the other Kindle.

Is there any way I can get round this? I would like to keep the same content on both devices.

The two Kindles do seem to know about each other and be in sync with the Amazon account, because I see warnings saying "Your last location in this book was..." on each device. So I'm not sure why content is not being shared.

Comment: if two kindles on one accounts does not register on other kindle, why am I paying for two @9.99 each?

Answer (score 1):

When you buy book from Kindle, it auto delivers the books to your chosen default device or the device you might be buying that book from. So by default you'd get the book delivered only on one device. So to get it on both devices you'd have to do it manually. Like when the "thanks" page appears you can deliver the book to your another kindle as well or from kindle you can view the book and click to download (as long as both use the same account) apart from that, kindle unlimited gives only one copy so that might not work on 2 kindles one account thing.